# Jmeter - Customize jmeter dashboard, convert kb to bytes on dashboard

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

Can we convert/Customize JMeter dashboard values in Statistics table from `KB/Sec` to `Bytes/Sec`?

Answer (score 0):

This is not something you can customise as per current JMeter version (JMeter 5.0)

However you can play a trick and multiply send/received bytes metrics by 1024 so JMeter will consider it kilobytes and in fact will be operating bytes.

1. Add [JSR223 Listener](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Listener) as a child of your [Test Plan](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Plan) (on global level as per [JMeter scoping rules](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-scoping-rules-the-ultimate-guide) so it will be applied to all the Samplers)
2. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   prev.setHeadersSize(prev.getHeadersSize() * 1024)
   prev.setBodySize(prev.getBodySizeAsLong() * 1024)
   prev.setSentBytes(prev.getSentBytes() * 1024L)
   ```
3. That's it, now you will have all metrics multiplied by 1024 therefore they will appear as bytes in the dashboard. You can also locate the *report-template/content/js/dashboard.js.fmkr* file (in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation):  and change this line:

   ```
   cell.innerHTML = "Network (KB/sec)";
   ```

   to something reflecting the new behaviour, i.e.  `Network (Bytes/sec)`